# The autoloader expected class

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony

I created code for tags in symfony but I have this bug:

> The autoloader expected class "Tag\TagBundle\Form\Types\TagsType" to be defined in file "/var/www/html/TagProject/vendor/composer/../../src/Tag/TagBundle/Form/Types/TagsType.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

**TagsType.php:**

```
<?php 

    namespace Tag\TagBundle\Form\Types;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Tag\TagBundle\Form\DataTransformer\TagsTransformer;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DataTransformer\CollectionArrayTransformer;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

    class TagsTypes extends AbstractType {

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
            $builder
                    ->addModelTransformer(new CollectionArrayTransformer(),true)
                    ->addModelTransformer(new TagsTransformer(),true);
        }

        public function getParent(){
            return TextType::class;
        }

    }
}
```

**TagsTransformer.php:**

```
<?php 

    namespace Tag\TagBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

    class tagsTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {

        public function transform($value){
            dump($value);
            return "";
        }
        public function reverseTransform($value){

        }
    }
```

**PostType.php:**

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Tag\TagBundle\Form\Types\TagsType;

    class PostType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('name')
                    ->add('content')
                    ->add('tags',TagsType::class);
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'appbundle_post';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you spot the problem? class TagsTypes ...

Comment: whey @cerad !!!

Comment: class name typo: `TagsTypes` => `TagsType`

Comment: thanks my friend @yceruto

Comment: The error itself said `The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is naming `class`.

You have TagsType.php is php file and your class name is `TagsTypes`:

You have to change `class` name:

**`class TagsTypes`**

to

**`class TagsType`**